# Youtube Channel_switcher

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

As of now, in oAuth process we get the list of channels associated with account.

Is there any API to get list of channels to give user chance to switch between channels?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is currently not possible. The only way you could let them switch between channels is to let them [reauthenticate themselfs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication) with another Google+ page.